# How to customize the border of Flutter Datatable Row, Column and Cell?

Tags: flutter, datatable

I have a black background Flutter app, and when adding Datatable widget, the border and text is not visible. 
I have added TextStyle color for all labels, but how do I do it for border?

```
DataTable(columns: [
    DataColumn(label: Center(child: Text('DATE', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)))),
    DataColumn(label: Center(child: Text('FANS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)))),
    DataColumn(
        label: Text('LIKES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))),
    DataColumn(
        label:
            Text('EST. EARNINGS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))),
  ],

      rows: [
        DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text('1')),
          DataCell(Text('2')),
          DataCell(Text('3')),
          DataCell(Text('4')),
        ])
      ]),
```

Comment: what about using Columns and Rows to create the same UI without using DataTable? is it fine?

Comment: check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart#L615

Comment: @pskink, can you please elaborate? Because i am quite new to Flutter, so I don't understand how to relate it to my problem

Comment: the colors are hardcoded

Comment: @Darish, that could work I believe, but I would like to see if it is possible to use Datatable in this case. Thank you for your suggestion. I would try that out if there is not much option left.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Theme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) widget and overriding the [dividerColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/dividerColor.html) will do the trick.

Here is the sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(_title),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.grey),
          child: DataTable(columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Container(
                width: 35,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'DATE',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Container(
                width: 35,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'FANS',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Container(
                width: 40,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'LIKES',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Container(
                width: 100,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'EST. EARNINGS',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ], rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  '1',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  '2',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  '3',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  '4',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ])
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the actual output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, it helped me a lot @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0

Comment: if i want to add margin or space of all column header then how can i do it